# EXCEL databaseconnection promt for password

Tags: excel

I have an EXCEL Workbook and in that I have a connection to an Oracle Database using OLEDB.

To do that I need to provide a userid and a password.

I would pefer not to store the credidentials in the workbook.
Is there any way I can avoide that, and have EXCEL promt the user for at password before the data is updated?

BR Kresten

Comment: How you are connecting to oracle database? You declare two variable for `userid` and `password` then pass these variable to `OLEDB` connection string.

Comment: I use the build in function in EXCEL to connect to datasources.